# How to search a user that has a letter (or a few) in his display name

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'll try to explain myself better.
I'm using C# to build a mini-program to myself. I want to search a user within my active directory, but I want to search a user without a full display name. Let me explain myself.
For example, my display name can be: "David Holonka\Jeramy".
Is there a way to search the letters "lonka" and it'll find me all the users that has these combinations of letters within their display name?

My current code:

```
using (var pc = new PrinicpalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MyDomain"))
{
UserPrincipal user = new UserPrinicpal(pc);
User.DisplayName = "Holonka";
PrinicpalSearcher scrh = new PrinicpalSearcher(user);
Prinicpal found = scrh.FindOne();
}
```

}

Right now it doesn't find anything becasue there isn't a user that its display name is only "Holonka", but I want it to find the user that i've mentioned before

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use query string in the `PrinicpalSearcher`:

```
UserPrincipal user = new UserPrinicpal(pc);
User.DisplayName = "*Holonka*";
PrinicpalSearcher searcher = new PrinicpalSearcher(user);
var results = searcher.FindAll();
```

You can also using `PrincipalSearcher` to find users with “or” parameters like in the example below:

```
List<UserPrincipal> searchPrinciples = new List<UserPrincipal>();
searchPrinciples.Add(new UserPrincipal(context) { DisplayName="*Holonka*"});
searchPrinciples.Add(new UserPrincipal(context) { SamAccountName = "*Holonka*" });
searchPrinciples.Add(new UserPrincipal(context) { MiddleName = "*Holonka*" });
searchPrinciples.Add(new UserPrincipal(context) { GivenName = "*Holonka*" });
List<Principal> results = new List<Principal>();
foreach (var item in searchPrinciples)
{
    var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(item);
    // Results may contains duplicate values because of separate searchers can handle the same user
    results.AddRange(searcher.FindAll());
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think about it

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using [Ambiguous Name Resolution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22653.active-directory-ambiguous-name-resolution.aspx), which is a special AD query that looks for partial matches in several attributes (the list of those attributes is in that article).

You can't use `PrincipalSearcher` do use ANR though. You have to use [`DirectorySearcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher) (which is what `PrincipalSearcher` uses in the background anyway).

Here's an example:

```
var searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://domain.com");
var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot) {
    Filter = "(anr=Holonka)"
};
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");

using (var results in = searcher.FindAll()) {
    foreach (SearchResult result in results) {
        if (result.Properties.Contains("displayName")) {
            var displayName = (string) result.Properties["displayName"][0];
            //do something else
        }
    }
}
```

When using `DirectorySearcher`, it's wise to use [`PropertiesToLoad`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.propertiestoload). If you don't, it will return every attribute that has a value, which is likely way more data than you need. It's a waste of network traffic and time.

The `using` statement is also wise, since [`SearchResultCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.searchresultcollection) can't be completely cleaned up by the garbage collector.

I wrote some more about that in an article I wrote: [Active Directory: Better Performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html)